# How to save bool from Database using Shared Preferences - Flutter (Part2)

Tags: flutter, dart, boolean

I have more code that I thinks work but I'm still having some issues. I change a bool value (that I reference from my app to my Firebase Realtime Database) then I want to save this bool locally. So I change a value referenced from my database but then I want to save it Locally. PS. The database is called People so when I write `People['Joined']` I am referencing the bool (Joined) form the database. I added the following code and I think I am getting somewhere but it still doesn't work:

```
//above the onpressed
savebool() async {
      SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      await prefs.setBool("People['Joined']", People['Joined']);
      print(People['Joined']);
    }

//onpressed:
onPressed: (BuildContext context) async {
              setState(() {
                People['Joined'] = true;

                savebool();
                print('saved');
              });


//IN MY MAIN.DART
late SharedPreferences prefs;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((value) {
      setState(() {
        prefs = value;
      });
      //load data
      _loadData();
    });
  }

  _loadData() async {
    bool joined = prefs.getBool("People['Joined']") ?? false;
    print('loadData :$joined');
    //this returns TRUE when i restart the app which is want I want but it doesn't remember that the color needs to change (see below)
  }
```

```
Widget listItem({
    required Map People,
  }) {
    //shared Preferences start
      savebool() async {
      SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      await prefs.setBool("People['Joined']", true);
    }
    //shared prefs end
    return Slidable(
      startActionPane: ActionPane(
        motion: const BehindMotion(),
        extentRatio: 1 / 5,
        children: [
          SlidableAction(
            backgroundColor: Colors.black,
            icon: Icons.add,
            label: 'Join',
            onPressed: (BuildContext context) {
              setState(() {
                //change value from false to true
                People['Joined'] = true;
              });
              //now i save it
              savebool();
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),...}
```

**What I think the problem is:** The value is returning true when I restart the app so it must be working, so the value is being saved but it doesn't work...I have written in my code `People['Joined'] ? Colors.green : Colors.blue,` so when it is true it will be green. But when i restart app it remembers that it is true but the color returns to blue. BECAUSE I am saving a variable called joined (see code) so it is saving that value and not `People['Joined']`...So how do i fix this?

Comment: `People` is a map?

Comment: you need to provide more code or something that we can run, hard to help you man, your code is all over the place

Comment: will do I added more code my bad man @AJ-

Comment: @Tyrone where is your `listItem` widget used? Why its `onPressed` is passing context? If you extract a Widget, you should do that in a stateless widget class, and have as parameter to that class an `onPressed` void Function, so that from your main widget, you can pass the setState method to your `listItem`

Comment: Do you suppose you can provide some code for better understanding. My `onPressed` function is from the slidable widget (just makes it so that the list item can slide and reveal buttons) and it cant be stateless widget because it is in my home page so it must be stateful @AJ-

Comment: @Tyrone I prepared an example for you and posted it

Answer (score 0):

you extract your ListTile to a stateless widget, and via parameters you pass from your `stateful` widget (your home page) the `setState` method and whatever else you need

```
class CustomListItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final Map people;
  void Function()? onPressed;

  CustomListItem({required this.people, required this.onPressed});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ThemeData theme = Theme.of(context);

    return Slidable(
      startActionPane: ActionPane(
        motion: const BehindMotion(),
        extentRatio: 1 / 5,
        children: [
          SlidableAction(
            backgroundColor: Colors.black,
            icon: Icons.add,
            label: 'Join',
            onPressed: onPressed,
          ),
        ],
      )
    );
  }
}


class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  void savebool() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await prefs.setBool("People['Joined']", true);
  }

  final Map people = {};


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ThemeData theme = Theme.of(context);

    return ListView(
      children: [
        CustomListItem(
          people: people,
          onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                //change value from false to true
                people['Joined'] = true;
              });
          }
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

something like this

Comment: Why do you extract it to a stateless widget?

Comment: because you should always exctract your UI widgets into stateless/ful widgets and not methods, you can read about more flutter best practices in the official documentation

Comment: When I change the bool form false to true it changes everything to true how can I make each individual one true?

Comment: @Tyrone you should put together the current changes into your code and if you have more issues or questions, open a new question, because I'm not sure what `form` you are referring to, that looks like another question